# How do I limit the files generated by DSBulk UNLOAD to just one CSV file?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I have run below command in EC2 instance to unload data from cassandra and store it at some place in EC2, But I observing that for each dsbulk unload command it generates 2 json files irrespective of how large or small the file size is.

How do I have control over how many files are generated? example, Suppose I want  a particular dsbulk unload to generate 5 part files instead of 2?

```
dsbulk unload -k custdata -t orderhistory -h '172.xx.xx.xxx' -c json -url proddata/json/custdata/orderhistory/data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour for the [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html) is to parallelise the tasks into multiple threads if the machine has multiple cores.

To limit the number of written files to a single CSV, set the file concurrency to 1 with:

```
$ dsbulk -maxConcurrentFiles 1 ...
```

Just be aware that this will limit the throughput of DSBulk since it will be single-threaded.

For details, see [DSBulk Connector options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/connectorOptions.html#_common_to_both_csv_and_json_connectors). Cheers!

**[UPDATED]** Use with a single dash (`-`) in `-maxConcurrentFiles` as advised by Alex Dutra/DSBulk dev.

Comment: Not working, Still it's generation 2 files after setting concurrency to 1:  dsbulk unload --maxConcurrentFiles 1 -k custdata -t orderhistory -h '172.xx.xx.xxx' -c json -url proddata/json/custdata/orderhistory/data

Comment: Are you sure it's generating 2 output files? Perhaps check the timestamps to make sure one of them wasn't generated from a previous run. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, They are generating two files itself. Checked the timestamp aswell

Comment: There is an error in the option: maxConcurrentFiles is a shortcut option and as such it should be introduced by a single dash: -maxConcurrentFiles 1

Comment: I opened https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk/issues/433.